# How to conditionally do if/then statement row wise in r data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, rowwise

Suppose I have two data frame like these:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
customer = c('john','sally','bill','david','sam','jake'),
coupon_id = c('a',NA,'d',NA,NA,'c'),
final_price = c(100,50,40,25,100,200))

df2 <- data.frame(
coupon_id = c('a','b','c','d'),
prct_off = c(.15,.2,.25,.50))
```

Goal: conditionally test each row of df1 to see if it has a coupon. If it does, multiply use the percent off it has in the df2 data frame to reduce the final price by the specified amount. If it doesn't leave the final price as is.

I think I'm close, but I'm failing to do things row wise. I'm doing something like,

```
df1$final_price <- ifelse(df1$coupon_id %in% df2$coupon_id, df1$final_price == df1$final_price*(1-df2$prct_off),df1$final_price)
```

but this doesn't work correctly.

Help?

Comment: This would be easier if you just `merge()` or `dplyr::left_join()` to combine your data first, then do the calculation.

Comment: Basically exactly the same problem as the question i've marked as duplicate.